# Is something wrong with this precalculus question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^{2}-4x+6=0$, then what can be the value of $1-\frac{4}{3x}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}$?

My answer is $1-\frac{4}{3x}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}=\frac{3x^{2}-4x+6}{3x^{2}}=\frac{3x^{2}-x^{2}}{3x^{2}}=\frac{2}{3}$ for $x\neq 0$. But according to the book answer is 2. What is the point i miss?

Comment: I agree with what you did, book may have a typo.

Comment: If $-3x^2-4x+6=0$ then it would be $2$.

Comment: Professor Somebody once said: "don't trust everything in your book."

Answer (score 1):

$3x^2-4x+6=2x^2+(x^2-4x+6)=2x^2$

You're right. Note that $x$ is complex and not real, but apart from this, the value of the other expression is $2/3$.